# PHP on Google App Engine fails to send a mail

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to send email in php using this code as it is given in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Sending_mail)

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';

use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;   //line 6 in my code

// ...

$message_body = "...";

$mail_options = [
    "sender" => "admin@example.com",
    "to" => "user@example.com",
    "subject" => "Your example.com account has been activated.",
    "textBody" => $message_body
];

try {
    $message = new Message($mail_options);
    $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // ...
}
```

and i am getting the following error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-home/mail.371603101929416156/save-email.php on line 6
```

Somehow appengine is throwing error on this line

```
use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;
```

Comment: Might be that you're using an older version of PHP.  Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php where it says it requires >= 5.3.0

Comment: It is hosted on Google App Engine with runtime as "php" and version as "1" in app.yaml

Comment: AppEngine currently uses PHP 5.4.19. I have use statements in my code which work fine as long as they are before any other code in the file (only require_once etc before).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your use statements are at the top of your code file, after the require_once but before any other code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions of IanGSY i have now put the import statements on the top

```
<? 
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
use php\sdk\google\appengine\api\mail\Message;
...
...
...
```

and that error is gone but now i am getting another error on this line

```
$message = new Message($mail_options);
```

Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'php\sdk\google\appengine\api\mail\Message' not found in /base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-home/mail.371604278238118648/save-email.php on line 29
```

Comment: The use statement should be:

    use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

Which you had correct in your original question.

Comment: Can you tell us all what you did to get it working? I'm also scratching my head with the same problem

Comment: The use statement should be: use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;